# Find().should is not a function in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to make an assertion on a wrapped element as below :

```
 cy.get('somelist')
    .each(($el, index) =>{
          if(condition1)
             cy.wrap($el).find('another_element').should('have.text', "TRUE")
          else
             cy.wrap($el).find('diff_element).should('have.text', "FALSE")
       }

Error:$el.find(...).should is not a function.
```

If I use cy.get instead of find(), then the assertions will be wrong.

Comment: With `cy.wrap` this should work. can you add the exact error for this? A screenshot works best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message doesn't match the code.

You can do this

```js
 cy.get('somelist')
    .each(($el, index) =>{
          if(condition1)
             const text = $el.find('another_element').text()
             expect(text).to.eq("TRUE")
          else
             const text = $el.find('diff_element').text()
             expect(text).to.eq("FALSE")
       }
```

The `$el.find()` is jQuery version and `cy.wrap($el).find()` is Cypress version.